# xamarin.ios does not support runnig or debugging the previous built version of your project

Tags: xamarin.forms, build, xamarin.ios

after I updated my Visual studio and xamarin.ios on mac. I m getting this error while trying to run ios project.

it connects to mac successfully but not able to deploy.

anybody have an idea about this.

please help.

Comment: Have you tried building it? Does it compile correctly? Try a Rebuild.

Comment: yes. itried clean,rebuild,build,deleting bin obj,basic steps

Comment: Is this a runtime issue or a compile-time issue? In case of a runtime issue can you show your output window or stack trace? Also, make sure you are using the correct provision profile!

Comment: compile time.and for running in simulator there is no need of provisioning profile.it is required when we want to run in device.so dont think issue bacause of that